# oracle sql developer missing on keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting the "missing on keyword" message on the following query and I'm not sure why:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_LINE_PRODUCT AFTER INSERT UPDATE OR DELETE ON 
TBL_CH08_LINE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN UPDATE TBL_CH08_PRODUCT P SET P_QOH = P_QOH-:NEW.LINE.UNITS
WHERE P.P_CODE = :NEW.P.P_CODE;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `OR`, in fact:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_LINE_PRODUCT
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TBL_CH08_LINE
-----------------^
    FOR EACH ROW
```

Oracle is expecting `ON` after the `INSERT`, which is why you get that particular error.